# Iterate over Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I was wondering how can I iterate over a binary search tree? Or is this not possible?

I have created a custom binary search tree and want to iterate over all existing elements.

Comment: Usually this is done by linking elements with each other, like a `LinkedList` (every element has a pointer to the next and previous element). Depending on your specific implementation of the tree, those pointers might already be given.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this. It depends if you use prefix, infix or postfix iteration over your tree.

Comment: If you just want to iterate over the tree and don't matter the order, it is quite simple. Just do a **DFS** or **BFS**.

Comment: It is linked with a ˋsingle LinkedListˋ, so i have the pointer of the next element.

Comment: Yeah, then just follow the pointers.

Comment: Also, if you want a specific solution, please consider showing us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
class MyNode
{
  private MyNode left;
  private MyNode right;

  void iterate()
  {
    // Iterate over left part
    if (left != null)
      left.iterate();

    // Do what you want with the current node

    // Iterate over right part
    if (right != null)
      right.iterate();

  } // iterate

} // class MyNode
```